# Unable to pass struct to pointer within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Given the following definitions:

```
#define arrayLengthInStruct 50

typedef struct {
   int _buf[arrayLengthInStruct];          
   int _bufLen;
} list;

// nested struct seems redundant but is there for some specific use
struct dev_req {   
    struct {    
        struct {       
            int src;
        }serviceReq;
    }_req;    
};
```

in main()

```
   int i=0;

// to pass the memory location
list g_src;                   // data is here
struct dev_req *dev_Areq;     // to be loaded/ transfer to here

   g_src._bufLen = arrayLengthInStruct;
// initialize the source
for (i = 0; i < g_src._bufLen; i++) {
    g_src._buf[i] = i+1;
    printf("%d \t", g_src._buf[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The next 2 lines are failing

```
   //dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src = malloc(sizeof(g_src));    // failed
   //dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src = (list*) &g_src;           // failed
```

It is also unclear if the next portion may work even after passing the previous 1 lines.

```
/*
for (i = 0; i < (dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src)->_bufLen; i++) {
    printf("%d \t", (dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src)->_buf[i]);
}
printf("\n");
*/
```

Comment: The line `g_src._bufLen = arrayLengthInStruct;`is not taking into account the size of the buffer, it is the amount of elements you are trying to put in. Also, if you're trying to dynamically allocate memort, shouldn't it be `int *src;`?

Comment: How shall I correct the program? 
I tried malloc'ing with **malloc(sizeof(g_src))**, but that did not work.

Comment: where is dev_Areq allocated? You're trying to access to the fields of an unallocated pointer.

Comment: In line `g_src._bufLen = arrayLengthInStruct;`, multiply `arrayLengthInStruct` by `sizeof(int)`; you have line `struct dev_req *dev_Areq;`, so you have a pointer, but never allocate memory for struct; In struct `dev_req`, since you using `src`as a pointer, ir should be `int *src`.

Comment: @Daniele, 

** struct dev_req *dev_Areq;     // to be loaded/ transfer to here **

Comment: which error do you get exactly?

Comment: If I uncomment the last 2 lines, it prints and hangs the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `dev_Areq` is a pointer type, the memory it points to not allocated yet.

```
dev_Areq = (struct dev_req *)malloc(sizeof(struct dev_req ));
```

Only after that, you can access its `_req` element.

second, you want point `src` to a `list` type, and access its element, then you should define `src` as `list *` type instead of `int`. Then point `src` to `g_src` using your this line:

```
dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src = (list*) &g_src;
```

Answer (score 1):

`dev_Areq->_req.serviceReq.src` is an integer, and you are trying to assign a pointer to it. This is wrong.

Comment: I emended src to int* src.
I am trying to put an address there.